# Outlook 365 Calendar API - Filter by Date

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi

I am having some difficulties getting the $filter property of an Outlook 365 query working. Any advice is appreciated.

My query works flawlessly until I add $filter to it, then it returns nothing.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Events?$filter=Start/DateTime ge '2016-07-21T07:00:00'&$select=Subject,Start,End,Categories,ShowAs,Sensitivity&$orderby=Start/DateTime&$top=10
```

My goal is to pull my calendar entries for just today. Once I figure out why the Start/DatTime filter is not working I'll be adding End/DateTime to be the same day with a different end time

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have spaces in the query, replace them with %20

Comment: @KevinGordon You should mark this as an answer if your question has been answered.